# Hello world works but then gets error that there's no main?

Tags: java, static

I have the following simple hello world in Java:

```
class A {
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

It works as expected, but oddly, it gives an error saying that the main method doesn't exist after.

```
$ javac A.java && java A
Hello world
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

Why? Should I ignore it? I even tried making a method called "main", but it changes nothing.

```
class A {
    static {
        main();
    }
    public static void main() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

---

```
$ javac A.java && java A
Hello world
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

Comment: ahhh the Main Pattern. i havnt seen in years

Comment: @DudeBro I hear it stronger than Singleton in some cases

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When your class is loaded, `static` initializers will be run, and then the JVM will try to invoke the `main` method. You can fix this by adding one more line to your `static` initializer:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    static {
        System.out.println("Look ma', no hands!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This will stop the JVM before it tries to invoke your `main` method.

Also note, this will not execute in Java 7. Java 7 looks for a `main` method before initializing the class.

Comment: OHHHH SNAP. This is the missing piece to the Main Pattern. I have search for solution for years.

Comment: Yes but how you maek it singletone?

Comment: This offends me in a very personal way.

Comment: I use `public static void main(String... ignored) { } ` ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Haha you write all that crap?

Comment: @megazord At least a few times a year ;)  I used to have a template to do it but I lost it.

Comment: Sooo this whole question has become a joke about the verbosity of Java?

Comment: Yep looks like it. Its useful as a way to challenge existing concepts. I found it difficult to explain why this is bad for reasons other than "just because"

Comment: hmm java 7 has bug. breaking Main Pattern break lots of existing legacy code

Comment: Why doesn't it work in Java 7? Is this change in the spec? I guess it's not so bad since I can't see a reason to switch to Java 7 so far.

Comment: @Dog I'm looking for a source, but in previous version of Java, a class was loaded, initialized, and then the `main` method was called. In Java 7, a class is loaded, the JVM looks for a `main` method, and if it finds one it will initialize the class.

Comment: Also WebStart didn't used to initialise the main-class before calling main.

Answer (score 11):

Its because your class is loaded by the class loader, static code is executed, then it searches for the main method and crashes as it doesn't exist.

Code in a class wrapped in a static block which is outside any method will execute upon first reference of that static class.

The reason it can't find your main method is you've declared it incorrectly.  Main looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){}
```

Get used to that line.  You'll see it many, many times.

The String[] args... argument is a list of space delineated arguments a user can pass to your program through a shell.  All programs enter through the main method.  This is a standard passed down for some time.

A static block could be used in a class to start your program, but it would cause confusion and be extremely improper.  Using a main method as an entry point is the industry standard.

I am unable to give a reason why this is the standard, or give a more convincing argument as to why to use it other than to get input into your program from a shell.  I do not suggest starting your program from a static block.

Answer (score 8):

Forget the `static` block, and do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You do need a `main` method.  In your last code example you've defined it wrong.  Define it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

You were missing the `args` that's why it still complained the second time.

@WilliamMorrison and @Jeffrey have explained why your program outputs "Hello world" and then it crashes.

There is a very good reason to use `main` instead of the way you're using the `static` block.  Mainly, that it's the entry point into your program.  You can't successfully run your program from the `java` command without one.  You can't execute a jar file without one.  And, as you've seen, you'll If you're missing a main, you'll get this error every time unless you write a hack to prevent it (see @Jeffrey's answer.  I don't mean that in an offensive way, his answer is very informative, but it is a hack IMO).

Another thing is that this is not idiomatic.  If I had to read your code I'd be wondering, "Where does this freaking code start?!"  I wouldn't be able to download it and figure out how to get my tools (IDE, maven, ant, etc) to run it.  Intellij doesn't know it *can* run a class without a `main` method.  That is the standard entry point into a program.

A random `static` block is not an entry point.  There's no way to pass arguments into it.  For example, if you wanted to write a command line program like unix's "cat" where you pass in a file name and it outputs the file contents, you couldn't do that with a `static` block because there would be no way to set and get the input.

Comment: Is there any reason other than to just get rid of the annoying error? That's a lot to type.

Comment: Thanks for the mention! You must always type the main.  That is the method signature java will look for to enter your program's logic.  If it doesn't exist, java doesn't know what to do.

Comment: I don't understand your edit. What do you mean by entry point? Clearly, the execution *enters* the static block.

Comment: @Dog You don't seem to understand how execution of a Java program works, then.

Comment: @Dog It is the defined beginning of the program, the static block you're using is for book keeping tasks. Its done at some point *while the class is loaded*, now your class might conceivably be used by annother proram, then all of a sudden your program leaps into life was well

Comment: the main method allows users to pass in string arguments.  Thats what that string array is.  If you didn't need string arguments I suppose you could use a static block, but it would be extremely improper to do so.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Indeed, lots of things technically work, doesn't mean they're a good idea

Comment: Agreed @RichardTingle :) I do not suggest this at all.

Comment: @Dog: How about my latest edit?  Does that explain things better?

Comment: I'm getting lots of downvotes on my answer.  I wish someone would tell me why.  Is something incorrect in what I've said?

Comment: @tieTYT Actually, you can predict the order the `static` initializers will be run in. Each `static` initializer will run the first time its class is being loaded. The main class will be loaded first, and then auxiliary classes will be loaded in the order they are used.

Comment: @Jeffrey but he doesn't have a main class.

Comment: @tieTYT The main class is the one passed to `java`, regardless if it has a `main` method or not.

Comment: " You can't run your program from the java command without one [main]." I just did, see the output in my question (above). "A random static block is not an entry point." So what? Why do I want to have an "entry point" whatever that is?

Comment: @Dog it would be more accurate to say you can't run your java program without it ending with an exception if you do not have a main method.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison: wrong see jeffry's answer, exiting fixes it

Comment: @Dog First, I gave many other reasons.  As to it running, yes but you got an error.  That's a reason in it of itself as to why you shouldn't do it.  If your code works but gives errors along the way, why would you argue for doing it that way?

Comment: @DudeBro "fixes" it. Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should do something, as RichardTingle said. I smell a troll :)

Comment: "If I had to read your code I'd be wondering, "Where does this freaking code start?!" wat. oviously if you do `java A` and you see `static` you know it is being executed... you dont no java?

Comment: @DudeBro how do **I** know to do `java A`?

Comment: @DudeBro Maybe it doesn't.  I don't need a readme to search for a `main` and that's what I and every other java developer would expect to find.

Comment: @Dog: Typing builds character.  Get a good IDE like Eclipse to fill in the boilerplate.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: You're telling me I should type more to build character but then you say to use an IDE (which would make me type less). Which is it? I write a lot of code outside the IDE because I want to see what it works like in the most reproducible environment possible.

Answer (score 2):

It works as expected, but oddly: No. class gets loaded. And when a class is loaded, its static blocks are executed.

Why you get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`

Because in first case you dont have a main method and in second case signature is not correct.

change it to `public static void main(String a[])`

Answer (score 1):

When classes are loaded to the JVM, it first "process" what is in the static block, which is why it prints out "Hello World" first, which explains this part:

```
class A {
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

When you run the program it looks for the "main" method, hence it prints out the `Hello World` first then looks for the main method, hence the error, same logic is applied when you call the method inside the static block.