# How this static block is executing in jdk 1.7

Tags: java, static, java-7

I am using jdk 1.7 in my application development. Some of the people I'm talking to are telling me that the static block will not execute in jdk 1.7 but this file is executing. Could anybody please explain this to me?

```
package com.treamis.util;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet;
    import org.apache.struts.action.PlugIn;
    import org.apache.struts.config.ModuleConfig;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

    public class HibernateUtil implements PlugIn {

        private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        static {
            try {
                sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
            }
        }

        public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
        }

        @Override
        public void init(ActionServlet servlet, ModuleConfig config) throws ServletException {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try writing a small program with a simple static block? (Though fwiw, I heard the same thing)

Comment: it is execute first, when your class burst.

Comment: "Some of the people I'm talking to are telling me" - Dont listen to people. Only java (or maybe Gosling) can tell you what it wants and how it works.

Comment: can u plz elaborate your answer thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static block is not executing in JDK 7, "Main method not found", but works in JDK 1.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500469/static-block-is-not-executing-in-jdk-7-main-method-not-found-but-works-in-jd)

Comment: hope this will be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500469/static-block-is-not-executing-in-jdk-7-main-method-not-found-but-works-in-jd

Comment: i have tried once but that not execute at that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Some of the people I'm talking to are telling me that the static block will not execute in jdk 1.7 but this file is executing

Let me re-phrase the statement. You cannot execute a class, which contains a `static` block, but no `main` method, form Java 7 onwards. You will get an error somewhat like - "Main method not found". However, you can use those classes from some other class. Of course you are not directly executing the `HibernateUtil` class right? That will be used from somewhere else in your application for handling `SessionFactory`.

Before Java 7, you were allowed to execute a class even though it didn't contain a `main` method but just a `static` block.

Answer (score -1):

I'm gonna explain this clearly... feeel free to ask ur doubts..
In previous version(before jdk 1.7)what actual process is it loads the classs file first, than the main file. Since we declared all the static class, methods, variables inside the class, it is loaded first. But later (jdk 1.7) the first it searches for main file. hence in latest versions we cant run any methods and classes without main. hope this helps....