# Set a variable and print it, without any threads, but it prints the old value?

Tags: java, security, unicode

I have a simple piece of Java code:

```
class A {
    static {
        int x=3;
        int y‭;
        int yy=1234;
        int yyy‮;y‭=1;int z‮y=x;
        System.out.println("x: "+x);
    }
}
```

I'd expect it to print "x: 1234".

```
javac A.java && java A
x: 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
```

But instead it prints "x: 3". Why? Is this another type of optimization I don't know about like volatile? I thought volatile only matters if you have multiple threads? I tried setting all variables to volatile, and even putting locks around them, but no luck. Someone told me I should set strictfp on the class, but no luck there either.

Comment: You have weird character encoding.

Comment: What output do you get if you just run javac A.java? If you still get x: 3... Well, then it's taught me something new.

Comment: This is what happens when dogs write code...

Comment: You've been posting all these questions with weird character sets. Are you just going for the upvotes because people are stumped at first?

Comment: Wow - a good example of WTF code.  Why are you setting a bunch of never-used local variables with meaningless names in a static initializer?  As for the actual issue, I'm guessing it's some weird feature of doing all this in a static initializer.  But I don't care, this is just deliberately strange code.  My only regret, paraphrasing Nathan Hale, is that I only have one downvote to give to this question.

Comment: @user949300: Well I found this during a security audit around part of our code that was recently outsourced but you can think whatever you want... Also, it has nothing to do with the static at all, this is the Main Pattern (http://stackoverflow.com/q/17496829/2213023).

Comment: @user949300: Why are you using Java if you don't care about how it works? You either know a programming language or you don't. It's incredibly irresponsible to program in a programming language that you don't know.

Comment: @Dog re: the "Main Pattern", you should read the responses to your question, where everybody says not to do that, they haven't seen it in years, it is not the industry standard, and it won't work in Java 7.

Comment: @Harold R. Eason  I said that this was WTF deliberately strange code.  You say that is malicious code, and you are almost certainly right.  We are in violent _agreement_.  Code like this should have been caught in a design review, somebody else glancing at it, etc...  In 15+ years of Java development I've never seen any legitimate code similar to this.

Comment: @user949300: (you are replying to my deleted comment which was replying to your deleted comment). You're being irrational. If someone made a backdoor like this, it's very unlikely that anyone would notice. Obviously it can be made to look more legitimate; Moreover OP said below that it's a stripped down version of an FEC algorithm. So yeah, I highly doubt that *you'd* notice this unless you understood the algorithm exactly (in which case you would have just wrote it yourself, or you're doing an audit, but most auditors I know don't bother with this kind of check).

Comment: @user949300: Basically, it's possible to write extremely hard to find backdoors using this, and you're saying we should not discuss the issue, and pretend it doesn't exist. I hope the entire Java community doesn't think this way...

Comment: I found this post here with another example http://vanillajava.blogspot.de/2012/09/hidden-code.html. I still don't understand how it works, though.

Answer (score 7):

You have characters that make displaying weird.
Actual code:

```
  1 class A {                                                                                                               
  2     static {                                                                                                            
  3         int x=3;                                                                                                        
  4         int y<202d>;                                                                                                    
  5         int yy=1234;                                                                                                    
  6         int yyy<202e>;y<202d>=1;int z<202e>y=x;                                                                         
  7         System.out.println("x: "+x);                                                                                    
  8     }                                                                                                                   
  9 }
```

<202e> is called "right-to-left override"
<202d> is "left-to-right override"

Comment: Chill, posted and tried to save in Eclipse and complained about encoding. It doesn't show special characters. Cool beans +1

Comment: What? Why is it showing `y=x` in yours but `x=yy` in mine? I'm guessing the `<202e>` before is just another type of semicolon?

Comment: @Dog Where do you get code like this? It has special characters all over it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Multilingual codebase in a big enterprise. I stripped down the code from an FEC algorithm.

Comment: @Dog, `<202d>`,`<202e>` are connected to changing right-to-left and left-to-right. You may investigate how they work exactly if you want

Comment: @Dog Related: http://www.infosecurity-magazine.com/view/20776/hackers-flip-over-unicode-trick/

Comment: Similar thing with homoglyphs. / There was briefly an underhanded C competition. The bottom line is that you can't effectively audit source code against maliciousness.