# running an algorithm without a Main class?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm learning Java from Introduction to Java Programming 9th ed. by Liang Y. D. and having some difficulty with one of the examples, pertaining to arrays. I would like to execute a sorting procedure with the following:

```
public class SelectionSort 
{
public static void selectionSort (double[] list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++)
    {
        double currentMin = list[i];
        int currentMinIndex = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++)
        {
            if (currentMin > list[j])
            {
                currentMin = list[j];
                currentMinIndex = i;
            }
        }

        if (currentMinIndex != i)
        {
            list[currentMinIndex] = list[i];
            list[i] = currentMin;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The problem is that there is no

```
Main (String[] args)
```

instead we have:

```
selectionSort (double[] list)
```

Now I would like to execute the above by

```
double[] list = {1, 9, 4.5, 6.6, 5.7, -4.5};
SelectionSort.selectionSort(list)
```

or any other combintion, but I keep getting Error: could not find or load main class. Is there a way to execute this in command prompt without loading the main class?

Comment: Create a TestSelectionSort class that has a main method and use this class in the test class's main.

Comment: Currently taking bets on when someone will suggest the use of a static initializer block . . .

Comment: @ruakh I went ahead and advised against it.

Answer (score 6):

Make a main class.

```
public class ArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] list = { };
        SelectionSort.selectionSort(list);
    }
}
```

Note: 
Do **NOT** do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17496829/758280). It is bad practice and will not work in newer versions of Java anyways.

Comment: +1. For that matter, for quick testing, this `main` method can be added to the existing `SelectionSort` class.